# Cannot rename abstractname when using babel (UKenglish)

Tags: environments, babel

I tried both redefinitions I found on tex.stackexchange, they have no effect:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This work is an \ldots
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Still renders as 'abstract':

[image]

Comment: I can't compile it

Answer (score 2):

So I followed my intuition, and you have to use the `addto` approach but replace `english` for `UKenglish`, like so:

```
\addto{\captionsUKenglish}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}}
```

Comment: I use similarly:
```tex
\addto\extrasbritish{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}}
```